# Can't get logon screen working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a login screen for my school A level project in Android Studio, but whenever I try to run the code, the emulator will run and then when the app tries to open, it crashes.

The code that I am using is:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static EditText username;
    private static EditText password;
    private static TextView attempts;
    private static Button login;

    int attempt_counter = 5;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        LoginButton();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void LoginButton() {
        Button Login;
        {
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
            attempts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_attempt_Count);
            Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

            attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));


            login.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (username.getText().toString().equals("user1") &&
                                    password.getText().toString().equals("password")) {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username and Password are correct",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.andrew.rewardsandsanctions.User");
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username and Password are not correct",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                attempt_counter--;
                                attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                                if (attempt_counter == 0) {
                                    login.setEnabled(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
            ;
        }
    }



    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Login Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

The errors that come up are:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.andrew.rewardsandsanctions, PID: 2925
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andrew.rewardsandsanctions/com.example.andrew.rewardsandsanctions.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
  at com.example.andrew.rewardsandsanctions.Login.LoginButton(Login.java:54)
  at com.example.andrew.rewardsandsanctions.Login.onCreate(Login.java:37)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Does the error "java.lang. NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'" shed any light on what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace indicates what the problem is:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Two things.  First of all, make sure you are getting a handle on your button appropriately.

`Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);` should probably look like this:

`login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);`

Secondly, make sure that the button with the id `button_login` exists inside your layout `activity_login`.

Once you verify that your button is non-null, then you may set your `onClickListener`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check your code, you have use "Login" variable and your assigning listener to "login":

```
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

    attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));


    login.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (username.getText().toString().equals("user1") &&
                            password.getText().toString().equals("password")) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username and Password are correct",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.andrew.rewardsandsanctions.User");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username and Password are not correct",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        attempt_counter--;
                        attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                        if (attempt_counter == 0) {
                            login.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have made the change but now I get 2 errors of:

Comment: cannot find symbol class login

Comment: edit your question again  and comment the line on which you get error

Comment: i cant get your line no. from here dude comment out the line on which crash occurs